# Show Git author in comments while writing commit message

Tags: git, identity-management

When I run `git commit`, my favourite editor starts and presents me with something like this:

```
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
# On branch master
# Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
#
# Changes to be committed:
# …
```

I work on many different projects in different context, and as such have various Git identities. More than once I have to change an existing commit (or worse, a chain of existing commits) because I forgot to run `git config user.email`.

Is it possible to show the current identity in the comments of the commit message, so that I see it when I write my commit message? That would help me to discover mistakes earlier.

Something along the lines of this would be fine:

```
# Author:
# jornane <jornane@example.com>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what OS you are using but on `Linux` you can achieve what you want using the following `prepare-commit-msg`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

# prepare-commit-msg: print author name and e-mail as a comment in a commit message
#                     automatically

# if amend, don't do anything
if ! [ -z $3 ] ;then
    exit
fi


author=$(git var GIT_AUTHOR_IDENT | grep -E -o ".*<.+>")

sed -i "1s/^/#$author \n/" $1
```

Comment: From your answer, I found http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Client-Side-Hooks, but that only applies to per-repo hooks. Since I forget to set the author, I would also forget to set hooks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293498/git-commit-hooks-global-settings seems to have more information on the matter, I'll look into that.